# How to change css property with function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change visiblty properties with a function.  I want when user click on the button change visible properties on textarea. How can ı make ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiV2n.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], _and be included in your question, not as an image_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

const changeVisibility = () => {
  setShow(!show)
}

return (
<>
    <div className="ui form">
        {show && (
            <div className="field">
                <textarea rows="2"></textarea>
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
    <button onClick={changeVisibility}>show</button>
</>  
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: its work. I think this way better than other way. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Make a state variable to keep track of the `textarea` visible state, then in the `textarea` tag, add style for using that state variable.
Then `onlick` event, toggle the state variable either to false or true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example.

1. Use `useState` to manage the visibility of the text area.
2. Attach a handler to the button that calls a function that updates the state.
3. Use a class called `hidden`. Initially the textarea won't have it but you can conditionally add it if the updated state tells you to.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ visible, setVisible ] = useState(true);

  function handleClick() {
    setVisible(!visible);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Toggle visibilty</button>
      <textarea className={!visible && 'hidden'}></textarea>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```